# SwifUI Picker fixed label

Tags: swiftui, constants, label, fixed, picker

I would like the picker label to be "Equipment", however when I launch the app it defaults to "DH4" (the first item in the enum) and when I select another item the label shows the newly selected item which I do not want. I want the label to always say "Equipment.

Ideas?

```
struct BidView: View {

var body: some View {
                    Picker(selection: $searchCriteria.equipment.bound, content: {
                       ForEach(Equip.allCases, id: \.self) { equip in
                          Text(equip.rawValue).tag(equip.rawValue)
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Equipment")
                    })
                    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Text(searchCriteria.equipment ?? "")
                
}

enum Equip: String, CaseIterable {
         case dash = "DH4"
         case max = "7M8"
         case triple7w = "77W"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to look somewhere else entirely. Wrapping my Picker in a Menu gives me the exact behaviour I was looking for:

```
     Menu {
          Picker(selection: $searchCriteria.equipment.bound, label: EmptyView()) {
                ForEach(Equip.allCases, id: \.self) { equip in
                    Text(equip.rawValue).tag(equip.rawValue)
                      }
           }
            .labelsHidden()
            .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
         } label: {
            Text("Equipment")
         }
```